# Find displacement function using mass and spring constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

A 3-kg mass is attached to a spring having spring constant $k = 300 N/m$. At $t = 0$, the mass is pulled down $10 cm$ and released with a downward velocity of $100 cm/s$. What is the resulting displacement?

I don't have a thorough example to use to help me with this problem. From what I have seen though, I think I have to solve $my'' + ζy' + ky = 0$. The only problem is that I don't know what ζ is (or what it means in the context of the problem). The back of the book says the answer is $y = (cos(10t) + sin(10t)) / 10$.

Comment: $\zeta = 0$.${}$

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: In your initial paragraph, there is nothing about $\zeta$. It's just a free harmonic oscillator.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\omega = \root{k \over m} = \root{300 \over 3}\mrm{sec}^{-1} = 10\,\mrm{sec}^{-1}}$

The general solution is given by:
\begin{align}
\mrm{y}\pars{t} &= A\cos\pars{\omega t} + B\sin\pars{\omega t}\implies
\mrm{y}'\pars{t} = -A\omega\sin\pars{\omega t} + B\omega\cos\pars{\omega t}
\\ &\
\mrm{y}\pars{0} = 10\,\mrm{cm} = {1 \over 10}\,\mrm{m} \implies A = {1 \over 10}\,\mrm{m}
\\ &\
\mrm{y}'\pars{0} = 100\,\mrm{cm \sec} = 1\mrm{m \over sec} \implies
B = 1\,\mrm{m \over sec}\,{1 \over \omega} = {1 \over 10}\,\mrm{m}
\end{align}
$$\bbx{\ds{%
\mrm{y}\pars{t} = \bracks{\cos\pars{10\,\mrm{sec}^{-1}\,t} + \sin\pars{10\,\mrm{sec}^{-1}\,t}}{1 \over 10}\,\mrm{m}}}
$$